# .NET - Multi threaded Producer Consumer using .NET reactive

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.reactive, producer-consumer

I am working to build a producer..consumer pattern using .NET reactive. Producer reads messages from Kafka message bus. Once the message is read, it needs to be handed over to the consumer to process the message.

I was able to do that using .NET reactive. However, I noticed that consumer is processing the message on the same thread as producer. Please see the code below. Objective is to: Have a single producer thread that reads messages from the bus. And, then hand it over to consumers on a separate thread to process the messages. The code I have is:

```
 // Producer Code
 private Subject<LGMessage> _onMessageSubject = new Subject<LGMessage>();

 private IObserver<LGMessage> messageBusObserver;

 protected IObservable<LGMessage> _onMessageObservable
    {
        get
        {
            return _onMessageSubject.AsObservable();
        }
    }


public void AddObserver(IObserver<LGMessage> observer)
    {
       _onMessageObservable.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer);


    }


// Read is called when the message is read from the bus
public bool Read(Message<string, string> msg)
    {

            // add the message to the observable
            _onMessageSubject.OnNext(msg.Value);


    }

// Consumer Code
public virtual void OnNext(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} Consuming",          

        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("{1}: Message I got from bus: {0}", value.Key, 
         this.Name);
        // Take Action
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be implementing your own observer and you're doing some non-idiomatic code. Can you post a [mcve] for us to see the full usage?

Comment: If you seem to think a hand coded multi-threaded equals better performance, you might want to benchmark it first. I would recommend going with the TPL.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from your code, but it looks like you aren't exposing the observable. This denies downstream usage of Rx operators. In your case, you would like to use [the threading operators](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SubscribeOnObserveOn).

In the producer, instead of exposing `AddObserver(IObserver<string> observer)`, I would expose something like this:

```
public IObservable<string> Messages => _onMessageSubject.AsObservable();
```

A consumer can then do something like

```
Messages
    .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(consumerObserver);
```

**EDIT**:

The following code works for me as intended:

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

var observer1 = new AnonymousObserver<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"Observer1: Observed {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}."));
var observer2 = new AnonymousObserver<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"Observer2: Observed {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}."));
var observer3 = new AnonymousObserver<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"Observer3: Observed {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}."));

subject.AsObservable().ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer1);
subject.AsObservable().ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer2);
subject.AsObservable().ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer3);

subject.OnNext(1);
subject.OnNext(2);
subject.OnNext(3);
subject.OnCompleted();
```

Here's the output (Observer1 got thread 14, Observer2 got thread 15, Observer3 got thread 16):

```
Observer1: Observed 1 on thread 14.
Observer2: Observed 1 on thread 15.
Observer1: Observed 2 on thread 14.
Observer1: Observed 3 on thread 14.
Observer2: Observed 2 on thread 15.
Observer2: Observed 3 on thread 15.
Observer3: Observed 1 on thread 16.
Observer3: Observed 2 on thread 16.
Observer3: Observed 3 on thread 16.
```

Comment: Thanks. After modifying the code, I can see that the consumer is processing the message on a separate thread. However, all consumers are processing the message on the same thread. I have updated the code. Can you please review and confirm if this is the correct pattern!

Comment: Thanks. I need to commit the message back to Kafka after the observer has processed the message. Is there a recommended pattern in reactive where an observer can notify the observable that the message has been processed successfully or not?